# Django dynamic multi steps form

Tags: python, django

I have a model, with a lot of non required fields. I want to have a multi steps form, like with `django-formtools`, but with the next form based of the answers of the precedent form...

For example,

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    # 1st form: generic informations
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    married = models.BooleanField()

    #2nd form
    # show it if married
    worth_it = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)

    job_status = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    #...
```

The first step of the form ask the generic information, and then in the second step the field "worth_it" is show to the user only if "married" was checked.

I know it's a bad model design, but i choose it to have a very flexible model that can be quickly adapted to the changing mind of the client..

Is there a way to achieve this, DRY and on server side ?
I thank about overloading the `get_absolute_url` method of the model to get a success url corresponding to the next correct form to update the model but i am searching a better solution.

Comment: How you ask the user to fill in forms has nothing to do with the model. Using the form wizard from the django-formtools could be a good approach. You can override methods to display or skip forms based on input in previous steps. But your question is impossible to answer specifically because it's too broad. You should dive in and try things and come back if you need help for a specific problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the model, but in the example a foreign key to table "marital status" could have been a cleaner alternative that having several optional fields dependent to each others. Which method of formtools to override ? I haven't seen anything to achieve dependent forms with formtools.

Comment: What i "tried" is as i mentioned override `get_absolute_url`, but it means having a specific view and url for each form, which is not very DRY, and done with a create and update way rather than true multi-steps forms. I admit its broad but i couldn't find anything more yet.

Comment: The [documentation of the `WizardView`](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps) shows exactly your case: how to conditionally view or skip a specific step.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted and i totally missed it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of the WizardView](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#conditionally-view-skip-specific-steps) from django-formtools shows exactly your case: how to conditionally view or skip a specific step based on a boolean entered in a previous step.